# When does a programmatically added fragment's view get created?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `FragmentActivity` that I add a single `ListFragment` to using `FragmentTrasaction`. All fine and well, but I have run into the "Content view not created" errors when trying to set the  `onItemClickListener` of the `ListView` in the `ListFragment`, like this:

```
public class ContactList extends FragmentActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener {

static private final String TAG = ContactList.class.getSimpleName();

private SimpleCursorAdapter mListAdapter;
ListFragment mListFrag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     mListFrag = new ListFragment();


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // add list view fragment
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mListFrag);
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set up list view adapter:
    mListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
            SimpleCursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

    // (we will switch in the cursor later)
    mListFrag.setListAdapter(mListAdapter);

    // set list view click listener:
    // (THIS LINE, I KNOW NOW, CAUSES PROBLEMS - SO I MOVED IT
    //  TO onCreateView):
    //mListFrag.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // initial cursor loader:
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

I quickly realised that I was trying to call `getListView` in the `onCreate` method, so the `ListView` was not being shown yet. So, I moved the line `setOnItemClickListener` line to `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);

    // set list view click listener:
    mListFrag.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); // this still crashes

    return v;
}
```

Unfortunately, this still crashes with a "Content view not yet created" error. I don't understand this - surely after calling `super.onCreateView` all of the views should have now been created?

I finally got the `inItemClickListener` to work by putting it on 'onResume()', but I don't know why it did't work in `onCreateView`.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fragment`s have own lifecycles and as I recall you can not set listeners on default `Fragment` lifecycle events from within the containing `FragmentActivity` (or any other `Activity`).
Therefore, you can not be sure if the list view has been created already if you use the default `ListFragment`.

> I finally got the inItemClickListener to work by putting it on
>   'onResume()', but I don't know why it did't work in onCreateView.

This might work for you, but also isn't safe because it has no knowledge of the Fragment's lifecycle state.

The default/best practice here is the following: write your own Fragment class, let it extend `ListFragment` and put the onClick logic in the [`onListItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method of your fragment.

**Background:**
Setting any listeners on UI events of a Fragment should happen inside the Fragment itself, not in the containing Activity. That's one of the reasons why Fragments have been introduced: to provide mostly independent components (with an own lifecycle) that can be combined and re-used. Otherwise, you could just use a `ListActivity`.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I forgot about the issue of separate life cycles.

Answer (score 0):

[OnCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onCreateView%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29) creates a view so it is available just after it return but not before or during execution.

Comment: Yes- but I call super.onCreateView before I set the onClickListener, so the views should be created by that point, yes?

Comment: There is no onActivityCreated in the FragmentActivity, that is a Fragment method.

Comment: yes it is, You have it in local v variable but getListView() doesn't have access to it because it wasn't returned yet.

Comment: @KernowBunney my bad I just took it from docs without checking. You have to stick to onResume then or move listeners to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

After `ft.commit` just call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` ([executePendingTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29)).

This forces the system to immediately execute the `ft.commit` which is only scheduled to be executed by default.

After that your ListView should be ready to be accessed to define the `OnClickListener` (inside your `FragmentActivity`)

Comment: @chucky Thanks - that sounds like it would work, but saschoar's answer  above highlights my fundamental oversight regarding the ListFragment having a separate life cycle. I guess it is not 100% guaranteed that the view has been created after the call to executePendingTransactions either....

Comment: According to the Docs it is, but I can't tell for sure!
I'm glad you found what you were searching for, and even if saschoar's answer is the one that fits you best you could upvote my post if others are experiencing similar problems like you did.

Comment: Sorry - this doesn't work: I still get a "content view not created" error. I guess that although the fragment has been forced to be added "now" by the call to `executePendingTransactions`, the lifecycle of the ListFragment (which is separate) has not got to the point where it has inflated the view.

Comment: Well that is strange... I tried it a few weeks ago and it worked without any problems. Sadly I recreated it from my memory here because I don't have that code snippet any more...